# How to make a Pandas count pivot table with related children items?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm stuck with a little problem with python and pandas dataframe.
I want to make a pivot table that count some relates items.
I got a dataframe with this structure.

```
+-----+------------+-----------+-----------+
| ID  | Item_Type  | Basket_ID | OwnerName |
+-----+------------+-----------+-----------+
|   3 | Basket     |           |           |
| 336 | ChickenEgg |         3 | Henk      |
| 841 | SomeEgg    |         3 | Henk      |
| 671 | EasterEgg  |         3 | Piet      |
|   9 | Basket     |           |           |
| 336 | Orange     |         9 | Piet      |
| 841 | Banana     |         9 | Piet      |
| 671 | Strawberry |         9 | Herman    |
| 888 | Apple      |         9 | Herman    |
| 821 | Apricots   |         9 | NaN       |
+-----+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to count how many items are related to the ‘Basket’ item (Parent) and how often the ‘OwnerName’ appears with the related ‘Basket’ item.

I want my dataframe like below.
You can see the total item count from the Items that are related with the parent Item_Type ‘Basket’, and the total count how often the name appears.
You can also see how many ‘Total_Owners’ are and also item without a owner.

```
+----+-----------+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+
| ID | Item_Type | Total_Items_Count | Henk_Count | Piet_Count | Herman_Count | Total_Owners | Total_NaN_Values |
+----+-----------+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+
|  3 | Basket    |                 3 |          2 |          1 |            0 |            3 |                  |
|  9 | Basket    |                 5 |          0 |          2 |            2 |            4 |                1 |
+----+-----------+-------------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question requires multiple steps but the core idea is that you should use pivot_table.

The table is conceptually a multilevel index. Basket ID is the high-level index and 'ID' is the more granular level index. First thing you have to do is remove the lines where basket_id is missing so that the granularity of the table is consistent.

Let's say you named your dataframe df.

```
#  Preparation steps  
df = df[~df["Basket_ID"].isna()]  # Remove the rows that shouldnt be counted.
df.loc[df["OwnerName"].isna(),"OwnerName"] = "unknown"  # set missing to arbitrary value

# Make a pivot table
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Basket_ID'],columns=['OwnerName'],values=['Item_Type'],aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
```

From there onwards you should be able to calculate your remaining columns

Comment: Thanks!, You helped me a lot with this!